# what are these two fm antenna connectors? How can I join them?

Tags: antenna, frequency-modulation

One of these connectors is the type that plugs into my receiver's FM antenna input, and the other is an aftermarket FM antenna output connector.  I think the one with threads is called "type F" but my searches are coming up with a lot of garbage, hence I'm not sure.  The other one I'm not getting even a poor answer.
[image: Is this ANT-108???? I have my doubts.]

Is this ANT-108?  I have my doubts.  The back of the receiver is, of course, the mating connector, and that's what I really need to join up with, not this thing.  But I can't easily
get a picture of the back of the receiver, sorry.

[image: I believe this is "type F"]
I believe this is "type F".

I want to join the bottom (type F) connector to the *mate* of the top connector.  Should I consider getting the mates to these two connectors and hacking up my own bit of wire between the two cables?  Or can you tell that this aftermarket antenna just isn't supposed to be connected to this kind of receiver?

Comment: Looks like you need a type N to type F adapter...  Search "N-Type Male to F-Connector Female Adapter"

Comment: @MarkU: neither of those connectors are a type N - N connectors are much bigger, and are not lilkely to be found on home equipment.

Comment: Do you know whether everything is 50 Ohm? Hopefully you don't have a mismatch of 50 Ohm and 75 Ohm stuff...

Comment: @mkeith Both the Belling-Lee and F connectors are 75 Ω.

Comment: @GrahamNye I have seen 50 Ohm F connectors. But I guess you are right. Practically speaking it is probably all 75 Ohm. My only cause for hesitation is that usually I think antennas, other than TV antennas, are 50 Ohm. But I may be wrong.

Comment: @mkeith 75-ohm is common in receive-only systems, 50-ohm is more common in transmitters and transceivers. 75 has lower loss for a given material & diameter, but 50 requires less voltage for a given power, which means more power handling for a given breakdown voltage.

Answer (score 2):

The first one is commonly known by the name "PAL connector". Also "IEC connector" (which is very vague, IEC has standardized zillions of connectors), or "Belling-Lee". It has similar properties to the F, but it's push-on rather than threaded. It's the common antenna connector in the parts of the world that used the PAL standard for analog TV, thus the name.

The second one is indeed an F connector. It's the most common connector for 75-ohm household coax in the USA.

If you search for an "F female to PAL male adapter" or even just "F to PAL" you shouldn't have much trouble finding the part you need.